# VFS file processing in WSO2 Esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am executing a sample given for VFS file processing, but during execution getting the error as "Cannot find the object for smooks config key: smooks". 
Could you please let me know what I have missed out?

Configurations made are as below.

Local entry for smooke is created with below configuration in smooke-key.xml

```
<localEntry key="smooke" src="file:/development/Dev/wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/resources/smooks-config.xml"><description/></localEntry>
```

==================================================================================

Smooke-config.xml is as below

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.0.xsd">

<!--Configure the CSVParser to parse the message into a stream of SAX events. -->
<resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
    <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVParser</resource>
    <param name="fields" type="string-list">name,value</param>
</resource-config>
```

Proxy service is as below

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="FileProcessor"
       transports="vfs"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
      <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <smooks config-key="smooke">
            <input type="text"/>
            <output type="xml"/>
         </smooks>
         <clone>
            <target sequence="fileWriteSequence"/>
            <target sequence="databaseSequence"/>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///development/Dev/fileProcessing/sourcefiles</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///development/Dev/fileProcessing/in</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///development/Dev/fileProcessing/error</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

create the smooks configuration at

```
 wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/samples/resources/smooks/Smooke-config.xml
```

and restart the esb

Answer (score 0):

change the localentry file like this

`<localEntry key="smooke" src="file:repository/resources/smooks-config.xml"><description/></localEntry>`